# From Start/End Date/Period to a long table for each day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'd like to transform a table containing Start Date and Lasting period (or equivalently End Date) to a long one, repeating the values for each day contained within the interval (extremes included). Here is an example.
From

| Name | Info 1 | Start Date | Period (day) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| Project 2 | Test 2 | 05/01/2022 | 2 |

To

| Name | Info 1 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 01/01/2022 |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 02/01/2022 |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 03/01/2022 |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 04/01/2022 |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 05/01/2022 |
| Project 1 | Test 1 | 06/01/2022 |
| Project 2 | Test 2 | 05/01/2022 |
| Project 2 | Test 2 | 06/01/2022 |
| Project 2 | Test 2 | 07/01/2022 |

I don't care about the order in the second table. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: Share a link to the spreadsheet, so that the volunteer contributors here have something to start with and a place to leave any working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

`=ArrayFormula(Array_Constrain({iferror(split(flatten(split(rept(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"❄️"&filter(B2:B,A2:A<>"")&"♥️",filter(D2:D,A2:A<>"")+1),"♥️",)),"❄️")),flatten(filter(C2:C,A2:A<>"")+sequence(1,max(D:D)+1,0))},sum(D:D)+2,3))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just don't know why two cells backgrounds become black.

Comment: I'm not following. Can you share your sheet or show a screenshot of what you mean?